# DVI to HDMI cable - No Video Input

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, dvi, external-display

I've just bought a DVI to HDMI cable in order to connect my Philips 227E3 to my Asus X555L.

When I connect them, and choose DVI as input for my screen, I get "No Video Input" message.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: so you are using the HDMI plug on the laptop and the DVI plug on the monitor, even though you have an HDMI plug on the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

HDMI is digital only. DVI can be digital and/or analog, known as DVI-I (digital+analog), DVI-A (analog), DVI-D (digital). So converters with DVI on one side and VGA (analog) or HDMI (digital) will work sometimes.

Consider DVI out on a graphics card. If it outputs digital and analog, then the adapter to VGA will work, as well as one to HDMI.

Consider a graphics card with only VGA and a monitor with DVI. If the monitor only accepts digital DVI-D then you get no picture.

The different DVI versions use different connectors. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) on the details how they look and compare with yours. The manual of your screen will maybe mention the accepted standards. So if the screen has DVI-A or a faulty DVI-I this might be the problem.

Beside problems cause by mismatched standards, the two devices may work in different resolutions. Nowadays screen can up-scale and down-scale, in order to display resolutions smaller and larger than their native resolution. But this has limits. HDMI is used in Full HD? A Chromecast HDMI has a problem to output a picture to an DVI WUXGA (1920x1200) for example. This is due to such devices talking to the display unit (screen, recorder, ...) first to see if the display properly follow the copyright mechanisms (HDCP). A Chromecast can turn black if it gets connected to a recorder. This is to protect Netflix etc.

So you see, digital brings clear, sharp picture with a price.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Asus notebook user's manual.  By default the video port for the external display is disabled on laptops/notebooks in order to conserve battery power and reduce electromagnetic emissions.
You have to explicitly enable output to the video port.
Typically the combination of the `Fn`key plus one of function keys (e.g. `F8`) controls this on laptops.